# Replace Desktop Power supply with Adapter based Power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a nice basic desktop with Pentium G4560 with a Crucial DDR4 RAM & Samsung EVO SSD. It worked nice and avg power consumption of ~45 Watt. The Power supply comes with a cabinet which costed around 20 USD (cabinet + power supply). I had the UPS in front.

The issue I am facing is the erratic electric supply which fluctuates between 130V to 230V. Mostly it is like 170V to 210V and sometimes it fluctuates too fast like 170 then 200 then back 170 like tens of times per minute. It leads to heating of UPS which sometimes shut off. And the annoying relay clicks continuously and beeps.

Now if you see the Optiplex 3080 micro and other normal Televisions they have power adapters. I feel the power adapter may solve my issue

**Question: Is it possible to convert/change a normal PSU to adapter based power supply.**

Motherboard is : GA-H110M-M.2

Open to ideas:
I am so desperate and can even purchase the OptiPlex micro (it has adapter based -laptop like) so avoid this headache if it will work.

Comment: These fluctuation can't be good for any of your appliances, I would suggest having an electrician install a whole house solution.  Honestly, I would consider adding solar to your roof to even out the power supply.  Although you need a whole house solution a 400w solar panel,battery, and inverter would be enough to power it under most conditions.   In the dark days of winter you might need more solar panels.

Comment: @cybernard I had setup the solar solution with around 360 watt already but it is still linked to normal inverter setup (in day use solar and in night use normal electricity to charge the single 160 AH battery). So when there was electricity cut - it worked well. I think need to use dedicated separate mini setup for WFH computer.

Answer (score 3):

> erratic electric supply which fluctuates between 130V to 230V. Mostly
> it is like 170V to 210V and sometimes it fluctuates too fast like 170
> then 200 then back 170 like tens of times per minute.

An external adapter will likely work the same as an internal power supply. I would not be inclined to change the computer power supply.

Try a true UPS for this:  A unit that chargers the UPS battery and an inverter circuit to power the equipment.

A UPS unit as I have described should absorb the external power fluctuations much better.

Check your AC supply and ask the Power Company about the fluctuations.

Comment: Came here to suggest you get a UPS. It should smooth out the power issues you are seeing, and give the added bonus of a backup if you experience a power cut (which given the issues you have, sounds pretty likely)

Comment: @john Yes this True UPS seems excellent! Any links you have. Yes already complained about to power company and hopefully they will get it fixed in upcoming few years

Comment: I use an APC (now Schneider) true UPS unit 750 watts of output power.

Answer (score 1):

Computer power supplies exist that are FULL range or approx 110v to 240v.

However, I have no idea how such rapidly changing voltage would affect it long term.

You may have to add some kind of line filter to even out the power supply from the mains.

Maybe some kind of capacitor.

Comment: I thought so about 110v to 240v but heard that they first take the base voltage like 110 v or 240v and then do some correction of say +/- X volt and they dont come cheap.

Comment: I also purchased and able to return a nice torroidal voltage stabilizer (line corrector) but that failed miserably as though it step up nicely but its output range is so wide like 195v to 260V and I can feel fans humming noise and again relay clicks and lot of beeps!

Comment: Why I am so much with power adapter as they does not seems to have any relay so no click click noises and they seems to work like my Televisions, adapter for my monitors etc